# Several rectangles cover the unit square. Can I find a disjoint set of them whose area is at least $1/4$?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I am interested in the following question:

> Let a finite sequence of rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be given such that
>
> 1. The edges of the rectangles are parallel to the coordinate axes, and
> 2. The rectangles cover the unit square, $[0,1]^2$.
>
> Is it possible to find, among these rectangles, a collection of mutually disjoint rectangles whose combined area is at least $1/4$?

As of yet, I'm not sure if a solution exists. My friend and I have spent a while thinking about this and have gotten nowhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where'd you come across this problem? This is very nifty looking.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It arose as a generalization of a puzzle my professor gave me. It turns out that if you cover an interval by intervals, you can find a disjoint collection whose length is at least $1/2$.

Comment: If you assume that every interval is needed in the covering (which you may by induction), then the intervals can be ordered from left to right. The even indexed intervals and the odd indexed intervals then each form disjoint collections, and one of them must have total length at least $1/2$. Unfortunately, this 'ordering' proof seems impossible to apply in two dimensions.

Comment: This was asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381180/choosing-disjoint-rectangles-with-large-total-area

Comment: If you allow the rectangles to overlap at the corner, then it is possible by four color theorem.

Comment: @AlonAmit - Close, but not quite: in that question, the ratio is to the total area covered by all the rectangles (thus the chosen solution, which uses overlapping rectangles covering areas of unbounded size). In this question, the ratio is to the unit square, so the solution there does not apply here.

Comment: I probably have no idea what I'm talking about, but if the sequence is finite, wouldn't the unit square itself be a solution - being a sequence of [one] disjoint rectangle which covers the unit square and whose sides are parallel to the axes?

Comment: @R.Burton, the union of the rectangles is the unit square - the unit square is not one of the rectangles necessarily.

Comment: @Lepidopterist Depends on what you mean by cover, some people would say that the unit square is simply contained in the union of the rectangles, and not equal to it.

Comment: @snulty Without loss of generality, we can assume that the rectangle is equal to the union, since we can just replace each rectangle by its intersection with the unit square.

Comment: Neither here nor in the similar question it is declared whether these rectangles are supposed to be open or closed, or neither. Similarly, whether rectangles sharing parts of their edges are considered disjoint.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: It doesn't really matter... assume they're closed (so "cover the unit square" is as easy as possible) and that rectangles just sharing edges are considered disjoint (so "mutually disjoint" is as easy as possible), and the answer is still "no" (for any constant $c>0$, not just $1/4$).

Comment: @achillehui Unfortunately, no. The 4 color theorem handles the case where the interiors are disjoint and overlapping at the corners is permitted, but mjqxxx's answer shows that allowing the interiors to overlap changes the problem. (I was going to post the same observation.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I think it would matter if you interpret the question as the area of the rectangles vs the area they intersect with the unit square, which is an ambiguity in this question and the linked one. I mean it just says area of the rectangles and they are subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$ rather than of the unit square. Although I do think the question means their area of the intersection with the unit square.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question linked by @AlonAmit in the comments answers exactly this question, and shows that the answer (at least with the constant $1/4$) is *no*.  For a concrete demonstration, start with a $6\times 6$ square broken into thirty-sixths:
$$
\begin{matrix}
0&1&2&3&4&5\\
6&7&8&9&a&b\\
c&d&e&f&g&h\\
i&j&k&l&m&n\\
o&p&q&r&s&t\\
u&v&w&x&y&z
\end{matrix}
$$
Now cover each corner $2\times2$ by four individual $(1+\varepsilon)\times (1+\varepsilon)$ rectangles, such that the four rectangles in the upper left ($0,1,6,7$) are mutually overlapping, as are those in each of the other corners.  And cover the remaining shape in the center (a cross) by eight individual $(3+\varepsilon)\times(1+\varepsilon)$ rectangles ($28e$, $39f$, $cde$, $ijk$, $kqw$, $lrx$, $fgh$, and $lmn$), such that all eight include the center of the square.  Any disjoint set of these rectangles includes at most four of the $(1+\varepsilon)\times(1+\varepsilon)$ rectangles and at most one of the $(3+\varepsilon)\times(1+\varepsilon)$ rectangles, and so has total area just over $7/36\approx 19.4\%$ of the full square.

Comment: Does a $(1+\epsilon)\times (1+\epsilon)$ rectangle have area $1+2\epsilon +\epsilon^2$? Which is a big square?

Comment: I would've thought theres arrangements where you cover 4 corners of the box, i.e. the four 2x2 squares, and the squares you've used are disjoint which would mean you've covered 16/36 of the area, since each letter represents 1/36 the area right? I must be misunderstanding something

Comment: @snulty: By $(1+\varepsilon)\times(1+\varepsilon)$, I mean covering a single small square plus a little extra.  There's no disjoint set of the rectangles I listed that cover a corner $2\times 2$, because each corner $2\times 2$ is covered by four mutually overlapping rectangles, of which you can only include one.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I changed it to say $6\times 6$ from the outset.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: I find this kind of answers very helpful, so I created an SVG image (https://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/unit-square-36.svg) you can use if you want to illustrate the covering. (Consider it public domain, or CC0-1.0 licensed.) The rectangles have rounded corners to make it easier to perceive the overlappings. The small squares areas are $\frac{1+\epsilon}{36} \approx 0.0278$ of the unit square, and the larger rectangles $\frac{3+\epsilon}{36} \approx 0.0834$. The largest disjoint sets contain four squares and one rectangle, for a maximum area of approx $0.1945$.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I find that graphic very helpful as well as the notation used was very off-putting for me. Thanks!